# How to stop database promises to block the main thread in Express server?

Tags: node.js, express

I have a NodeJS server and I try to use promises to do calls to my database so my server will still be able to deliver other clients with faster queries.

Here's the simplest code I could do:

```
const express = require('express');
const server = express();
const moment = require('moment');

require('dotenv').config();

const slowRoute = require('./routes/slow');
server.use('/slow', slowRoute);

server.listen(process.env.PORT, () =>
    console.log(
        `Listen on port ${process.env.PORT} | ${moment().format(
            'YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm:ss:SSS'
        )}`
    )
);
```

and my router

```
const express = require('express');

const router = express.Router();
const pool = require('../database');

router.get('/', async (req, res, next) => {
    console.log(`Slow route`);
    let result = await pool.query('SELECT pg_sleep(6)');
    res.status(200).json(result.rows[0]);
});

module.exports = router;
```

If I call 2 times the /slow, the second console log "Slow route" only trigger after the 1st complete and the result come 12 seconds after instead of 6.

I succefully do 2 calls at the same time in the past, I just don't understand why I can't do it now.

Answer (score 0):

The `await pool.query('SELECT pg_sleep(6)')` do rest of your  code stop until it finish

see [await MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await)

U can do

```
router.get('/', async (req, res, next) => {
  console.log(`Slow route`);
  pool
   .query('SELECT pg_sleep(6)')
   .then( result => {
     res.status(200).json(result.rows[0]);
  })
})
```

Ps: I don't run this code